# Safari Mobile full screen

Tags: iphone, web-applications, fullscreen, iphone-standalone-web-app, metatag

I'm trying to set the full screen mode on my iPhone Web App, I have read the Apple's documentation on apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag, but it doesn't work, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Have you added it to your home screen and launched it that way? It won't work in normal Safari.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also add a javascript function :

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 100);">
```

Comment: this works for the url bar, but is there a way to hide navigation bar at bottom?

Comment: more on this javascript hack here : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/

Answer (score 16):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

Make sure you do what Bala Clark mentioned

> Its worth mentioning that these tags only work when the app is saved
>   the home screen and launched from there

Comment: thoses meta tags are only working for iOs safari and only if the user added the website to his home screen.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that these tags only work when the app is saved the home screen and launched from there.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in iOS 7, and yes, I am launching from the saved home screen icon.

Comment: I had the same problem until I found the answer that Bala Clark mentioned. You have to add the site to your home screen by selecting the box with up arrow in safari and then add to home screen, this is for ios 8, I have not tested in other versions of ios