# Full screen website on android and IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, web-applications

I create website with angulaJS and responsive bootstrap.

The question is I want my website run in full screen mode or remove the address-bar.
My user use IOS safari IOS chrome android browser and android chrome

Comment: Are you talking about a website or webapp? Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143637/safari-mobile-full-screen

Comment: @Turnip website

Comment: You can't do that on iOS. I don't know about Android.

Comment: @Turnip what about web application?

Comment: iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6143684/746736. It looks like it may be possible on Android: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

Answer (score 0):

is it helpful ?
Controller:

```
 function MainCtrl($scope, Fullscreen) {

  $scope.goFullscreen = function () {

  if (Fullscreen.isEnabled())
     Fullscreen.cancel();
  else
     Fullscreen.all();

  // Set Fullscreen to a specific element (bad practice)
  // Fullscreen.enable( document.getElementById('img') )

  }

 }
```

HTML:

```
 <button ng-click="goFullscreen()">Enable/Disable fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: i don't use that on my app but it's pretty similar

Comment: @ArthurBelhandouz Fullscreen is not defined

Comment: you can find help with this i think https://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen